# deleting knex migrate_lock table - is it safe?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I actually stopped a rollback migration midway, now I don't really know what the problem is, it won't rollback migrations any more. I used the command: `knex migrate:rollback --knexfile=knexfile-client.ts --verbose <name>` for rollback.

What I do know is these records are kept in the `migrations` and `migrations_lock` that postgres creates automatically, **I was wondering if the problem will be solved if I delete these two. Would they regenerate making things fully functional again? I mean my database is heavy, and I'd like to avoid pulling and recreating everything.**

Currently this is the error:

```
$ knex migrate:rollback --knexfile=knexfile-client.ts --verbose
Requiring external module ts-node/register
Using environment: development
FS-related option specified for migration configuration. This resets migrationSource to default FsMigrations
FS-related option specified for migration configuration. This resets migrationSource to default FsMigrations
migration file "20210413082306_create_find_report.ts" failed
migration failed with error: drop table "find_report" - table "find_report" does not exist
error: drop table "find_report" - table "find_report" does not exist
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:357:11)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:186:21)
    at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:101:30)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:313:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:288:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:227:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I've triple checked `find_report` table exists from pgAdmin. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm actually using a make script to run above command so that I don't actually have to specify the file name

Comment: have you tried using `with()` to specify the database ?

Comment: The error that is coming from the database says it doesn't exist, so you have been checking it from different place that knex does. Dbserver doesn't lie.